# JUnit error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, intellij-plugin

I encounter a weird issue with JUnit testing. I added a new rule to my BNF file which results in creation of a new token FOO. Running the plugin works fine and the token and element is shown in PSI View. However, when executing a UnitTest it fails with:

```
de/foo/bar/psi/impl/FooBarImpl
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/foo/bar/psi/impl/FooBarImpl
    at de.foo.bar.psi.FooTypes$Factory.createElement(FooTypes.java:424)
    at de.foo.bar.parser.FooParserDefinition.createElement(FooParserDefinition.java:63)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.CompositeElement.createPsiNoLock(CompositeElement.java:705)

...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.foo.bar.psi.impl.FooTinesImpl
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:215)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 40 more
```

The class reported as not found is available.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working by deleting the folder `build/classes` from root of my plugin folder.